# I need the name for a shape

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns

What is the name for a shape comprising a circle and seven attached lobes?
Septlobate?
Heptlobate?
Something other?

Comment: Can you supply an illustration?

Comment: Seven Up!......

Comment: Did you notice that was a vey specific, prolly geometric, term having nothing to do with any every-day language?

If your suggestions help, they should prolly be Septlolobate or Heptlolobate. Does that difference make sense?

Answer (score 0):

Florate? 'Like a flower'

I think it's Septo - not just sept
Septolobate

And Hepta - not just hept
Heptalobate
Example - heptagram

But maybe I'm wrong about hepta as here it says just hept:
https://www.google.co.id/search?q=hepta+prefix&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&hl=en-id&client=safari

There is also poly-lobate (many-lobed form)

Comment: It would be *hepta-* before a consonant and *hept-* before a vowel. The table reproduced from phrontistery.info doesn't tell the full story. Other results on that page do.

Comment: Most flowers have showy parts (petals, sepals) that are multiples of 3, 4 or 5.